# Getting a reference to a textbox in order to dynamically change the font

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am unfamiliar with Flash and actionscript and I need help to dynamically change the font of a textbox based on the value of a flashvar. I have a flash template whose content I can edit through XML. The flashvar value specifies the language and points to a different XML file. This works without problems, and I have found online a way to change the font via actionscript. However I need help on how to get a reference to that textbox.

There are two files an .fla and Main.as file. Within the fla file there is a single Scene and when the textbox is selected the properties display "thisLogo" as its name and "Dynamic Text" in the combo box below. Within the Main.as file I have attempted to add the following code:

```
//...
public class Main extends MovieClip {
    private var _root = root as MovieClip;
private var _parent = parent as MovieClip;

private var xmlURL:String = 'xml/main.xml';
    //...

    public function Main() {
        var myflashvars:Object = new Object();
    if (!this.loaderInfo.parameters.language){
            myflashvars = {language: ""};
    } else{
    myflashvars = this.loaderInfo.parameters;
    }

        var langvar:String = myflashvars['language'];
    xmlURL = 'xml/main' + langvar + '.xml';

        var myformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    myformat.font = "Arial";
    //thisLogo.embedFonts = true;

        //This is the part I do not know how to reference the textbox from the code.
    _root.thisLogo.setTextFormat(myformat);
        //I have also tried:
        //this.thisLogo.setTextFormat(myformat);
        //thisLogo.setTextFormat(myformat);
```

Obviously the error I receive is the following:

1119: Access of possibly undefined property thisLogo through a reference with static type Main.

Answer (score 0):

First I would suggest adding an `if` statement that tests whether the `Main` object's stage property is not null before executing the rest of the code. If it is null(which is usually isn't) then you can add an event listener that listens for your `Main` object to be added to the stage:

```
if (stage) init();
else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
```

Next you get the reference to your textfield and store it in a local `TextField` object by calling the `stage` property's `getChildByName()` method and parsing the name of your textfield(I'm assuming its "thisLogo"?). Then you convert the `DisplayObject` object returned by the `getChildByName()` method to `TextField`.

```
var thisLogo:TextField = TextField(stage.getChildByName("thisLogo"));
```

Now try

```
thisLogo.setTextFormat(myformat);
```

Overall it should look like this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.text.TextField;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var xmlURL:String = "xml/main.xml";

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var myflashvars:Object = new Object();

            if (!this.loaderInfo.parameters.language)
            {
                myflashvars = { language: "" };

            }
            else
            {
                myflashvars = this.loaderInfo.parameters;

            }// end else

            var langvar:String = myflashvars['language'];
            xmlURL = 'xml/main' + langvar + '.xml';

            var myformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myformat.font = "Arial";

            var thisLogo:TextField = TextField(stage.getChildByName("thisLogo"));
            thisLogo.embedFonts = true;
            thisLogo.setTextFormat(myformat);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```